# ngOnDestroy being called after ngOnInit

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have this situation: 2 of my pages use a global service to provide trainings (`trainingService`. This service has a `loadTraining(type)` and a `destroyTraining(`type`). ;

Both pages use the same component (`TrainingPage`) where `type` is a parameter:

```
{ path: 'training/:trainingType', loadChildren: './pages/training/training.module#TrainingPageModule' },
```

`TrainingPage` calls `destroyTraining` on `ngOnDetroy` and calls `loadTraining` on `ngOnInit`, the problems is that when I change from training1 to traininig2 the order of calls is something like:

```
 ngOnInit -> ngOnDestroy
```

So my `trainingService` gets into a weird state. Is there some way to be sure ngOnDestroy is called before the next component is instantiated?

Comment: Can't you call your `destroyTraining` in the same place where you're switching training type?

Comment: If both pages use the same component then you should provide the service at component level not global level in module.

Comment: @Jojofoulk yes, but if I switch to another page, say `HomePage` the subscriptions to the active Training Class are not destroyed.

Comment: @NirajOza that services holds the configuration to be used. It is also used in another component `ConfigComponent` that is inside the `GlobalConfiguration` component and holds the info about the active Training from the service. That is why it is a global service.

Comment: Then I suggest to use either obeservable through behaviour subject or do better state management using ngrx so component to component state will retain at service level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular does it on purpose, It's the correct way that should be. `ngOnDestroy` it's the last of the **lifecycle-hooks**.

They are called in this order:

1. ngOnChanges()
2. ngOnInit()
3. ngDoCheck()
4. ngAfterContentInit()
5. ngAfterContentChecked()
6. ngAfterViewInit()
7. ngAfterViewChecked()
8. ngOnDestroy()

You can see the information here:  https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

You should change the way you work with the `service`, without destroying it or making it component level.

Comment: Making it at component level is not a possibility to me but you are right, I have to change how the service work taking into consideration the lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide service at the component level, not in the global level or module level

```
@Component({
/* . . . */
  providers: [trainingService]
})
```

so the same component used in two different places will create separate instances of service.